# How do I Build or Run .Net Core2 Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]

I have tried creating asp project using either dotnet cli or visual studio 2017, any time i try to run the project in both cases, i get this strange error. 
this how how i created a sample angular project. dotnet new angular in a folder
called angular

> ```
>   Angular.csproj: [NU1202] Package 
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 is not 
>   compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package 
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 supports: 
>   netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this may have been a bug with this specific version of Dot Net core, I found this thread:

> https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000759144-Compile-Microsoft-CSharp-Core-targets-84-5-MSB6004-C-Program-Files-dotnet-sdk-2-1-2-Roslyn-RunCsc-cmd-

Which suggests copying the `RunCsc.cmd` from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Roslyn\bincore` to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Roslyn`

I would suggest to check the installation of your dot net core, this seems very weird.

Hope this helps

Comment: do we copy or cut

Comment: Probably just copy it for now

Comment: that other problem has been solved, but                                         
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 is not 
  compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package 
  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 supports: 
  netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)   still remains

Comment: Sounds like your installation is not completely correct or the template has generated weirdly, I would suggest spinning up a console app to see if that works, if not, then reinstall .Net Core, both CLI and sdk, sorry not sure what else to suggest

Comment: console app works, the only problem is dotnet web apps

Comment: Quick question are you building from CLI? If so you may want to do a `dotnet restore` before `dotnet build`

Answer (score 0):

finally this is what worked for me

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```